# org-mode: Can I use a custom mode for org-src-lang-modes and still get syntax highlighting?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I'm trying to get syntax highlighting with org-mode source blocks using a custom language mode for editing JavaScript. I use `js2-mode` with a bunch of minor modes, rather than `js-mode`, which is what org-mode uses by default.

I was able to get org-mode to use `js2-mode` for editing code by customizing `org-src-lang-modes`, where I set the `Cons-cell` for `javacript` to `js2`.

However, syntax highlighting has stopped working in the org buffer (it works fine in the source buffer). This is with `org-src-fontify-natively` set to true, which the documentation suggests is the only requirement.

Is there anything I'm missing?